# Use function from Model in Notifications Laravel

Tags: laravel, function, model, notifications

How can I use functions of the model in the notifications of laravel?

i want to use this function:

```
 public function isFollowed()
    {
        return $this->followers()
            ->where('follower_id', auth()->id())->exists();
    }
```

i get the follow error: `Call to a member function isFollowed() on array`
This is my current code:

```
<a class="@if($notification->read_at)@else unread-notification @endif min-height-60" href="#">
        <img class="rounded mt-5" src="{{ Storage::url( $notification->data['user']['avatar'] ) }}" width="45" height="45" alt="" />
        <small class="float-right" style="color:#666">{{$notification->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</small>
        <h5 class="fs-11 text-black mt-10 mb-0"><b>@if( Auth::id() == $notification->data['user']['id'] OR $notification->data['profile']['privacy'] == 1 OR $notification->data['profile']['privacy'] == 2 OR $notification->data['user']->isFollowed(Auth::id()) ){{$notification->data['user']['username']}}@else AC @endif</b> hat dein Post kommentiert: <b>{!! $notification->data['comment']['body'] !!}</b></h5>
    </a>
```

if i use

```
$notification->data['user']['id']->isFollowed(Auth::id())
```

Then i get the follow error:

```
Call to a member function isFollowed() on integer
```

Comment: is `$notification->data['user']` looks like its an array. Try `$notification->data['user'][0]`

Comment: yes, its an array. If i use your code, i get the follow error: `Undefined offset: 0`